# Serialized array save to mysql with php and orderby

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is javascript serialized array:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7}]},{"id":8}]}]
```

How to save this (dynamic) to mysql with php like this:

```
***********************************
|  id  |   subsite_id  | orderby  |
   1           0            0
   2           0            1
   3           0            2
   4           3            0
   5           4            0
   6           4            1
   7           4            2
   8           3            1
***********************************
```

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Do you know how to deserialize it? Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to make a query?

Comment: How does that JSON correspond to that table?  How do you know what to put in each field?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Things in `children` get put in with a `subsite_id` corresponding to their parent and everything gets put in `orderby` dependeng on its position in the array that contains it.

Comment: @minitech: Ah, yes.  I see that now :-)

Comment: query call: UPDATE sites SET subsite_id='$subsite_id', orderby='$ordeby' WHERE id='$id';

Comment: I think you probably want `INSERT`. And no quotes. And PDO.

Comment: @minitech: No, i want UPDATE while this is array from "drag table" and i don't know how to create foreach to save this in database (sortabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the *best* solution, but it's certainly *a* solution.  Recently, I learned about [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php)s and their cousin, [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).  So, I took it upon myself to use them in everything I code (relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/208/).

I hacked this up quickly:

```
class ChildIDIterator implements RecursiveIterator{
    private $_array;
    private $_position = 0;
    private $_parent;

    public function __construct(array $array, $parent=0) {
        $this->_array = $array;
        $this->_parent = $parent;
    }

    function valid(){
        return isset($this->_array[$this->_position]);
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->_array[$this->_position]['id'];
    }

    function next() {
        $this->_position++;
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->_position = 0;
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->_position;
    }

    function hasChildren(){
        return isset($this->_array[$this->_position]['children']);
    }

    function getChildren(){
        return new self(
            $this->_array[$this->_position]['children'],
            $this->_array[$this->_position]['id']
        );
    }

    function getParent(){
        return $this->_parent;
    }
}
```

This recursively iterates over your (decoded) array and returns the id values.  To use it, you can do this:

```
$json = '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7}]},{"id":8}]}]';

$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$iterate = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new ChildIDIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterate as $order=>$id){
    echo "UPDATE sites SET subsite_id={$iterate->getParent()}, orderby={$order} WHERE id={$id};\n";
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/57189

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad I could help :-D